# nth triangular number and division algorithm

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $t_n$ denote the nth triangular number. For what values of n does $t_n$ divide the sum  $t_1 + t_2 +...+ t_n$ ?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. 
In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you write what your thoughts 
are on the problem and include your efforts (work in progress) in this and future posts 
and in what context you have encountered the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $t_n = n(n+1)/2$,
you should be able
to get an expression for
$s_n = \sum_{i=1}^n t_n$.

From this,
you should be able
to decide when
$n$ divides $s_n$.

Comment: **THANKS** , Now by Mathematical Induction I proved that $s_n = \frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{3}$ , then I divided $s_n$ by $t_n$ so after simplifying I have got $\frac{2(n+2)}{3}$ ,therefore I concluded that $t_n$ divieds $s_n$ iff $3$ divieds $(n+2)$ . **Is this solution true ?**

Comment: I think that $s_n = n(n+1)(n+2)/6$. Try n=1 and 2.

Comment: Yes, you're right $s_n=\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{6}$.  Then after simplifying I have got $\frac{(n+2)}{3}$,so $t_n$ divides $s_n$ iff $3$ divides $s_n$ .

Comment: I think you mean 3 divides n+2, or n is of the form 3k+1 for some integer k.

Comment: Exactly, that's what I meant . Sorry It was a typo !

Answer (score 1):

In particular, the cumulative sum of elements $\binom i 2$ in the second diagonal of Pascal's triangle is a specific element $\binom ? 3$ in the third diagonal. Think about it.

[image]